# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Tags: android, исключения

Кто может подсказать в чем дело.?

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class SecondActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> stationsList;

private static String url_all_stations = "localhost://stations.php";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_STATIONS = "stations";
private static final String TAG_PID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name_station";

JSONArray jsonArray = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    stationsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

new LoadAllStations().execute();

class LoadAllStations extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SecondActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Загрузка остановок. Подождите...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_stations, "GET", params);

        Log.d("All Stations: ", json.toString());

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_STATIONS);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    stationsList.add(map);
                }
            } 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        SecondActivity.this, stationsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                        TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

st

```
03-14 11:12:08.535 2806-2844/com.example.max777.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.execute
                                                                                at com.example.max777.myapplication.JsonParser.makeHttpRequest(JsonParser.java:50)
                                                                                at com.example.max777.myapplication.SecondActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(SecondActivity.java:118)
                                                                                at com.example.max777.myapplication.SecondActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(SecondActivity.java:96)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
03-14 11:12:10.516 2806-2806/com.example.max777.myapplication E/WindowManager: Activity com.example.max777.myapplication.SecondActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40f77f60 that was originally added here
                                                                           android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.max777.myapplication.SecondActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40f77f60 that was originally added here
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
                                                                               at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
                                                                               at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
                                                                               at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
                                                                               at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
                                                                               at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
                                                                               at com.example.max777.myapplication.SecondActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(SecondActivity.java:108)
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
                                                                               at com.example.max777.myapplication.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:50)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: ну так в `execute` разве не надо строку подавать?

Comment: стактрейс ошибьки в студию

Comment: Без логов ошибки, её типа и точной строки её возникновения помочь вам решительно невозможно.

Comment: `onPostExecute` и так работает в UI потоке, зачем `runOnUiThread`???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030660/ наверное